# How to deal with this.state's asynchronicity

Tags: asynchronous, react-native, asyncstorage

Doing this:

```
onPress={() => {
          this.setState({
            myArray: []
          });
          const { myArray } = this.state;
          console.log(myArray);
        }}
```

Expect the array to be empty, but it still contains old values. If I press the button again, or console.log at a different place in the program, the array is empty. I take it this is due to this.state being asynchronous. This is a problem since, instead of the console.log, I'm planning to have the array saved to `AsyncStore`like this:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem(
  "@ShoppingListStore: ShoppingListKey",
  JSON.stringify(myArray) 
);
```

If I can't save the array directly after the state has been set, where can I do it? Is there a way to listen for the state to complete setting, then run the AsyncStore code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
onPress={() => {
          this.setState({
            ...this.state, myArray: []
          }, () => console.log(this.state.myArray));
        }}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for enlighten me Nicolas! :)